# Use two columns in Case when

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am calculating five columns based on two columns using Case When. But it's not giving correct value. I have attached screenshot of correct result.
Results needs to be like:
Business Logic is - These five calculated fields has different definitions and dependent on predecessor filed. Definition of EER is, If an ID passes from a certain queues and also doesn't pass queue like FBR, CVL and CSP. EER field should have Yes in all rows of one ID. This goes on same way for rest four calculated fields as in case when statement. Once EER calculated, EES should be calculated for rest of IDs. So I used EER needs to be null for EES. An ID has Yes in one of five field it will be null in rest four field for same ID.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [QUEUE] varchar(7), [EER] varchar(4), [EES] varchar(4), [EEN] varchar(4), [EBNP] varchar(4), [NSB] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [QUEUE], [EER], [EES], [EEN], [EBNP], [NSB])
VALUES
    (24017879, 'LOCCLOS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes'),
    (24017879, 'OTBCUST', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes'),
    (24017879, 'CVLPLAN', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes'),
    (24017879, 'LOCSCHD', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes'),
    (24017879, 'LOCINST', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes'),
    (24017879, 'BDWXNG', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes'),
    (24017879, 'RESOLVE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes'),
    (24017879, 'BDWPLAN', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes'),
    (24048916, 'PORSCHD', NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (24048916, 'VCECNFG', NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (24048916, 'VCEROUT', NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (24048916, 'LOCCLOS', NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (24048916, 'OTBCUST', NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (24019969, 'LOCCLOS', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL),
    (24019969, 'OTBFUTR', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL),
    (24019969, 'BDWCNFG', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL),
    (24019969, 'OTBCUST', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL),
    (24019969, 'RESOLVE', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL),
    (24019969, 'FBRWORK', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL),
    (24019969, 'BDWMSPR', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL),
    (24019969, 'BDWPLAN', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL),
    (180614, 'BDWROUT', 'Yes', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (180614, 'BDWCNFG', 'Yes', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'RESOLVE', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'LOCSCHD', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'CSPWORK', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'BDWPLAN', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'LOCINST', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'LOCCLOS', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'OTBNGOM', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'OTBTSKD', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'BDWXNG', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'OTBFUTR', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'BDWROUT', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL),
    (23893585, 'BDWCNFG', NULL, NULL, 'Yes', NULL, NULL)
;
```

My attempt is:

```
Select Distinct X.ID,X.Queue,
case when X.Queue in ('IPTEST','IPPRV','IPPRECF','IPPMOM','IPCON','IPCFG','BDWXNG','LOCCLOS','BDWCNFG','BDWROUT')
and X.Queue not Like '%FBR%' and X.Queue not Like '%CVL%' and X.Queue not Like '%CSP%'
then 'Yes'else 'Null' end AS EER,
case when EER = 'Null' and X.Queue not in ('CSPWORK','CSPRACK','CSPEQUP') and X.Queue not Like '%FBR%' and X.Queue not Like '%CVL%'
then 'Yes'else 'Null' end AS EES,
case when EER = 'Null' and EES = 'Null' and X.Queue Like '%CSP%' and X.Queue not Like '%FBR%' and X.Queue not Like '%CVL%'
then 'Yes'else 'Null' end AS EEN,
case when EER = 'Null' and EES = 'Null' and EEN= 'Null'and X.Queue not Like '%CVL%'
then 'Yes'else 'Null' end AS EBNP,
case when EER = 'Null' and EES = 'Null' and EEN= 'Null' and EBNP = 'Null' and X.Queue Like '%CVL%'
then 'Yes'else 'Null' end AS NSB

From X
```

Actual Result -

[image]

Comment: Are those your expected results above? It seems you forgot to include your sample data, so we don't know how to get that result. Can you supply both sample and expected result please?

Comment: First calculate only one column and evaluate the result ask question about one column. So I will easy for us also

Comment: Thank you for response. Expected results has been attached above. Sample data will be first two columns of above data. These five columns are interdependent. If one column calculated correctly, I can do rest four myself. Probably, This case when stuck in my mind.

Comment: so what output is incorrect?  The values you give are inputs, the SQL you give does not give the same values of EER that you gave in the input - is that the problem?

Comment: in the first row 'LOCCLOS' is in your list of 'IN' conditions, but it is NOT LIKE any of the exceptions you asked for - so NOT LIKE '%FBR%' will be TRUE - for example - the whole thing seems to evaluate to true - ie. it boils down to 'true and true and true and true' which becomes 'true'

Comment: You compare `EER = 'Null'`, but you do not have a string literal with the value `'Null'`, you have a `NULL` value. Check like this: `EER IS NULL`.

Comment: Hi All, I have tried to make it easy to understand.

Comment: It's confusing that you're reusing column names for things which are completely different in the output. Be aware that all expressions in a single `select` are computed "as if" they're being assessed in parallel. You cannot make one expression depend on the *result* of another expression, if that's what you're trying to do (but reusing the column names hid this problem from you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (**updated query**):

```
;with [data] as (
    select [id], [queue] from [Table1] group by [id], [queue]
)
,[eer] as ( 
    select
         [id]       =   [x].[id]
        ,[queue]    =   [x].[queue]
        ,[eer]      =   [eer].[eer]
    from
        [data]  as  [x]
    outer apply (
        select [eer]    = iif(      (exists (select null from [data] where [id] = [x].[id] and [queue] in ('IPTEST','IPPRV','IPPRECF','IPPMOM','IPCON','IPCFG','BDWXNG','LOCCLOS','BDWCNFG','BDWROUT')))
                                and (not exists(select null from [data] where [id] = [x].[id] and ([queue] like '%FBR%' or [queue] like '%CVL%' or [queue] like '%CSP%')))
                            , 1, 0
                        )
    )               as  [eer]
)
,[ees] as ( 
    select
         [id]       =   [x].[id]
        ,[queue]    =   [x].[queue]
        ,[eer]      =   [x].[eer]
        ,[ees]      =   [ees].[ees]
    from
        [eer]   as  [x]
    outer apply (
        select [ees]     = iif(     [x].[eer] = 0
                                and (not exists (select null from [data] where [id] = [x].[id] and [queue] in ('CSPWORK','CSPRACK','CSPEQUP')))
                                and (not exists(select null from [data] where [id] = [x].[id] and ([queue] like '%FBR%' or [queue] like '%CVL%')))
                            , 1, 0
                        )
    )               as  [ees]
)
,[een] as ( 
    select
         [id]       =   [x].[id]
        ,[queue]    =   [x].[queue]
        ,[eer]      =   [x].[eer]
        ,[ees]      =   [x].[ees]
        ,[een]      =   [een].[een]
    from
        [ees]   as  [x]
    outer apply (
        select [een]     = iif(     [x].[eer] = 0 and [x].[ees] = 0
                                and (exists (select null from [data] where [id] = [x].[id] and [queue] like '%CSP%'))
                                and (not exists(select null from [data] where [id] = [x].[id] and ([queue] like '%FBR%' or [queue] like '%CVL%')))
                            , 1, 0
                        )
    )               as  [een]
)
,[ebpn] as ( 
    select
         [id]       =   [x].[id]
        ,[queue]    =   [x].[queue]
        ,[eer]      =   [x].[eer]
        ,[ees]      =   [x].[ees]
        ,[een]      =   [x].[een]
        ,[ebpn]     =   [ebpn].[ebpn]
    from
        [een]   as  [x]
    outer apply (
        select [ebpn]    = iif(     [x].[eer] = 0 and [x].[ees] = 0 and [x].[een] = 0
                                and (not exists (select null from [data] where [id] = [x].[id] and [queue] like '%CVL%'))                               
                            , 1, 0
                        )
    )               as  [ebpn]
)
,[nsb] as ( 
    select
         [id]       =   [x].[id]
        ,[queue]    =   [x].[queue]
        ,[eer]      =   [x].[eer]
        ,[ees]      =   [x].[ees]
        ,[een]      =   [x].[een]
        ,[ebpn]     =   [x].[ebpn]
        ,[nsb]      =   [nsb].[nsb]
    from
        [ebpn]  as  [x]
    outer apply (
        select [nsb]     = iif(     [x].[eer] = 0 and [x].[ees] = 0 and [x].[een] = 0 and [x].[ebpn] = 0
                                and (exists (select null from [data] where [id] = [x].[id] and [queue] like '%CVL%'))                               
                            , 1, 0
                        )
    )               as  [nsb]
)
select 
     [id]       =   [id]            
    ,[queue]    =   [queue] 
    ,[eer]      =   iif([eer]   =   1, 'Yes', null)
    ,[ees]      =   iif([ees]   =   1, 'Yes', null)
    ,[een]      =   iif([een]   =   1, 'Yes', null)
    ,[ebpn]     =   iif([ebpn]  =   1, 'Yes', null)
    ,[nsb]      =   iif([nsb]   =   1, 'Yes', null)
from  
    [nsb]
order by 
     [id]       asc
    ,[queue]    asc;
```

Comment: Thanks @Juozas , This has corrected in positive direction. Actually I am looking one Yes again one ID as given in needed result above. Your code is giving multiple Yes for one ID.  This solution - 
ID         Queue         EER   EES EEN   EBNP   NSB
180614 BDWCNFG Yes   Yes Null    Yes Null
180614 BDWROUT Yes   Yes Null   Yes Null`

Comment: I cannot understand your task. Please describe in simple words what do you try to achieve: business logic instead of query. For every of columns to be calculated. Its impossible to understand business logic from your query provided, as query logic and desirable results are misleading.

Comment: I am sorry if it's not good to understand. I have updated definition and attached screen shot also.

Comment: You have error for column [EER] in your "right" results screenshot. [ID] 24048916. 
[ID] 24048916 has [QUEUE]  LOCCLOS, and not contains any of FBR, CVL, CSP. So, [ERR] column for ID  24048916 needs to be "Yes". But you have null. Its confusing. Your task is complicated, so, it is very strong recommended to avoid any errors in your description, if you want help.

Comment: @LearnerBee I updated my answer by new logic. Please use new query provided. Keep in mind - its very possible, that your results screenshot has error.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @HoneyBadger, you should do IS NULL check instead of equality operator. Note no two NULLs are equal, since NULL is just a mark to denote absence of value.

So the query should be.

```
Select Distinct X.ID,X.Queue,
case when X.Queue in ('IPTEST','IPPRV','IPPRECF','IPPMOM','IPCON','IPCFG','BDWXNG','LOCCLOS','BDWCNFG','BDWROUT')
and X.Queue not Like '%FBR%' and X.Queue not Like '%CVL%' and X.Queue not Like '%CSP%'
then 'Yes'else Null end AS EER,
case when EER is Null and X.Queue not in ('CSPWORK','CSPRACK','CSPEQUP') and X.Queue not Like '%FBR%' and X.Queue not Like '%CVL%'
then 'Yes'else Null end AS EES,
case when EER is Null and EES is Null and X.Queue Like '%CSP%' and X.Queue not Like '%FBR%' and X.Queue not Like '%CVL%'
then 'Yes'else Null end AS EEN,
case when EER is Null and EES is Null and EEN is Null and X.Queue not Like '%CVL%'
then 'Yes'else Null end AS EBNP,
case when EER is Null and EES is Null and EEN is Null and EBNP is Null and X.Queue Like '%CVL%'
then 'Yes'else Null end AS NSB

From X
```

Comment: I am really thankful for your efforts.But this is not giving correct result. I have attached a screenshot of correct results.

Comment: Is your "ansi_NULL" set on ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql